# Remove already selected value from a combobox in datagridview

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagridview, combobox, wpfdatagrid

I have a wpf datagridview and and combobox in the template column. I do not want to show the values already selected for other rows, but in doing this the item that is currently selected also gets removed.

The model is as follows

```
public class MetadataConfigurationModel : ViewModelBase
{        
    private ObservableCollection<MetadataConfiguration> _metadataConfiguration = new ObservableCollection<MetadataConfiguration>();
    public ObservableCollection<MetadataConfiguration> MetadataConfig
    {
        get { return _metadataConfiguration; }
        set { _metadataConfiguration = value; }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<TaxonomyField> _taxonomyList = new ObservableCollection<TaxonomyField>();
    public ObservableCollection<TaxonomyField> TaxonomyList
    {
        get
        {
            ObservableCollection<TaxonomyField> tempTaxanomy = new ObservableCollection<TaxonomyField>(_taxonomyList);
            tempTaxanomy.Add(null);
            tempTaxanomy.Move(tempTaxanomy.Count - 1, 0);
            foreach (MetadataConfiguration mdConfig in _metadataConfiguration.ToList())
            {
                tempTaxanomy.Remove(mdConfig.Field);
            }
            return tempTaxanomy;
        }
        set
        {
            _taxonomyList = value;
        }
    }

    public class MetadataConfiguration : ViewModelBase
    {

        private TaxonomyField _field;
        [XmlIgnore]
        public TaxonomyField Field
        {
            get { return _field; }
            set
            {
                _field = value;
                _isDirty = true;
                _fieldName = _field == null ? String.Empty : _field.Title;
                _fieldGUID = _field == null ? Guid.Empty : _field.Id;
                _termsetGUID = _field == null ? Guid.Empty : _field.TermSetId;
                OnPropertyChanged("Field");
            }
        }

        private string _fieldName;
        public string FieldName
        {
            get { return _fieldName; }
            set { 
                _fieldName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FieldName");
            }
        }

        private Guid _fieldGUID;
        public Guid FieldGUID
        {
            get { return _fieldGUID; }
            set { _fieldGUID = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FieldGUID");
            }
        }

        private Guid _termsetGUID;
        public Guid TermsetGUID
        {
            get { return _termsetGUID; }
            set { _termsetGUID = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TermsetGUID");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The ViewModel populates the list as follows

```
_model.TaxonomyList = new ObservableCollection<TaxonomyField>(_lstTaxonomyFileds);

if (_model.MetadataConfig.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (MetadataConfigurationModel.MetadataConfiguration mdConfig in _model.MetadataConfig)
    {
        mdConfig.Field = (from a in _model.TaxonomyList where a.Id == mdConfig.FieldGUID select a).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

And the xaml is as follows:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="dgMetadataConfig" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding MetadataConfig, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="10,0,0,0" CanUserAddRows="False" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Field Name">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox Width="170" SelectedItem="{Binding Field, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.TaxonomyList, Mode=TwoWay, 
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}},
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                              Margin="2,2,2,2" DropDownOpened="CmbTaxonomyField_DropDownOpened" DisplayMemberPath="Title" SourceUpdated="CmbTaxonomyField_SourceUpdated"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In the viewmodel I have a list _lstTaxonomyFileds that I am using in populate the TaxonomyList in the model. This list contains say three items "AB", "BC" and "CD". Now the user adds the first row to the grid and have all three options in the combobox and selects "AB" now adds another row and will now have only "BC" and "CD" in the combobox until he deselect "AB" from the first row.

Comment: What does *I do not want to show the values already selected for other rows* mean?

Comment: Like in the first row I have selected "ABC" then for any other row "ABC" should not appear in the combobox.

Comment: That *sounds* like you have data bound the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` property of each item to a single property, but your XAML seems fine. I can only therefore assume that *your code* is causing this problem.

Comment: Yes, the get block of TaxonomyList property in the model is doing the removing but in doing so it removes all the selected values including the one that is for the current row and I cannot find a way how I can prevent it from removing the current selected item.

Comment: What's wrong with leaving them all selected? You should be careful of producing an application with unnatural behaviour as that tends to confuse users.

Comment: I think I was not able to express myself correctly. In the viewmodel see I have a list _lstTaxonomyFileds that I am using in populate the TaxonomyList in the model. This list contains say three items "AB", "BC" and "CD". Now the user adds the first row to the grid and have all three options in the combobox and selects "AB" now adds another row and will now have only "BC" and "CD" in the combobox until he deselect "AB" from the first row and that I think will be very friendly for the user. And I think I should not have added the FieldName and TermSetGUID properties in this question.

Comment: That information should be in your *question* where it will be read, not in a comment, although I accept that you were responding to me. As for your requirements, you won't be able to use a single property as the `ComboBox.ItemsSource` *and* remove items from it. Instead, you'll have to use a different collection for each row and manage them all in your `MetadataConfigurationModel` class... it'll be a pain. That's quite a requirement that you have there. Just to be clear at this stage, that's too much to answer for most people here, so good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an ideal solution but somehow I was able to make it work. Moved the TaxonomyField property in the MetadataConfiguration class, did some linq magic and binded it to the itemsource.